# Box-shadow with rgba variable

Tags: css, css-variables

So I want to have a box-shadow with a Color variable in it. I saw on a post here that `rgba(var(--card-border-color),0.75);` works fine but having this inside a box-shadow Attribute breaks it. So this dosnt work:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0.46rem 2.18rem rgba(var(--card-shadow-color), 0.03),
    0px 0.93rem 1.4rem rgba(var(--card-shadow-color), 0.03),
    0px 0.25rem 0.53rem rgba(var(--card-shadow-color), 0.05),
    0px 0.12rem 0.18rem rgba(var(--card-shadow-color), 0.03);
```

How can I work around that?

Comment: What values are you setting `--card-shadow-color` to? When I use `--card-shadlow-color: 0, 0, 0;` as a proof-of-concept it works. See https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/z6xvkaye/

Comment: `--card-shadow-color: #040914;`

Comment: You can't: that is not supported because `rgba(#040914, 0.33)` for example, is not a valid CSS value (it is parsed by SCSS as valid CSS though). You need to convert the hex code into its rgba components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be working fine, given that the following condition is satisfied: **after the injection of the variable your color property is a valid CSS value**. When you are using a hex code, this interpolates to `rgba(#040914, 0.33)` for example. This is *not* valid CSS—as per my comment, it is valid SCSS though, because the parser will convert it into a valid CSS RGBA color string.

What you need is to deconstruct/convert your hex color into its RGBA counterpart for it to work, so that it will interpolate to something like `rgba(4, 9, 20, 0.33)`. This is done by doing:

```
--card-shadow-color: 4, 9, 20;
```

See proof-of-concept below:

```css
.box {
  --card-shadow-color: 4, 9, 20; /* RGB equivalent of #040914 */
  
  box-shadow: 0px 0.46rem 2.18rem rgba(var(--card-shadow-color), 0.03),
    0px 0.93rem 1.4rem rgba(var(--card-shadow-color), 0.03),
    0px 0.25rem 0.53rem rgba(var(--card-shadow-color), 0.05),
    0px 0.12rem 0.18rem rgba(var(--card-shadow-color), 0.03);
    
  /* Presentational styles */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 1px solid rgba(var(--card-shadow-color), 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```